# Scope is not updating if used inside of callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically I have a listener function in the controller. When this function is called I want to update my UI/scope, but it is not happening. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
        Main {{mainCtrl.foo}} <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var my = {};

my.MainCtrl = function() {
  this.foo = 'waiting';
  this.notifier = new other.Notifier();
  this.notifier.addListener(this.update.bind(this));
}

my.MainCtrl.prototype.update = function() {
  this.foo = 'updated';
  alert('Updated');
}

// register all controllers
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', my.MainCtrl);

var other = {};

other.Notifier = function() {
};

other.Notifier.prototype.addListener = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
};
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/vj5D7/1/

Comment: You need to call `$scope.$apply()` if you update something outside of an angular digest cycle.

Comment: why do not use `$timeout` instead `setTimeout`. I suggest to use pure angular and only in specific cases to use jQuery.

Comment: I use setTimeout only as an example, in my case I'm listening for messages from external services (chrome messaging)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the common hangups people have with AngularJS.

setTimeout does not trigger `$scope.$apply()`. If you used angular's own `$timeout`, it would do that for you.

I see you're not using any $scope variables. I'm not familiar with that newer syntax.